# SSH tunneling is blocked only when at work and only when connected to VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-tunneling

I would like to be able to `ssh tunnel` into a machine that is connected to a VPN at work.

**Setup**

- `Machine A` - Creates the `SSH tunnel` in Machine B
- `Machine B` - Connects to the work `VPN`

Situation

```
╒═════════╤══════════════╤═════════════════════╤══════════════╤═════════════════════╕
│         │ Work Network │ Work Network on VPN │ Home network │ Home network on VPN │
├─────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Can SSH │ Yes          │ No                  │ Yes          │ Yes                 │
╘═════════╧══════════════╧═════════════════════╧══════════════╧═════════════════════
```

As you can see. It is not the VPN that is blocking my being able to `ssh` into `Machine B` as I am able to connect to the VPN on the same machine at home. So it is the work network that is blocking this but **ONLY** when I am connected to the VPN.

I am changed the `ssh` port to `2222` and `17832` but this made little difference, once connected to the VPN the connect will time out.

I am confused, is it possible that at work they block `ssh tunneling` but only when somebody is connected to the `VPN`?

Comment: It is pretty difficult to understand what you want to do, could you rephrase? A possible answer as far as I understood: there could be a firewall at your company, which blocks some ports.

Comment: I think to sum up :) and sorry its confusing. When I am at home with the same laptop. I connect to our work VPN and then I can tunnel into that machine successfully. When I am at work and i use the same machine and connect to the same VPN, I am unable to ssh tunnel in.

Comment: I have updated the question Jue... I hope it is more clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the VPN technology on question and client software, and especially in Corporate settings, VPNs usually install network routes diverting the usual flow of traffic.

Often they can also download firewalling policies that forbid you doing pretty much anything besides the intended use of connecting to the resources behind the VPN *while* the VPN is active for security reasons - namely using the VPN client as a jump hop/tunnel to another networks.

So the problem you are facing, could well be and most probably is a setup intentionally done by design. Other than that, I would advise talking with your local network team, they can give you far much more concrete answers than here.

Comment: Thanks Rui, its as I feared then. What gets me most though is that at home I am able to ssh and tunnel, exactly how I would like to. So its 100% NOT the VPN that is the problem.

Comment: Policies can also be different from where you connect to the VPN, and often in corporate wifi you cannot connect from one client to the other. With the kind of details you give we can only speculate about the standard practices in the industry.

Comment: Well I work for a bank :) So indeed they can have more than one policy for the same network depending if you on the VPN or not basically. If this is possible, then yes I believe they will have blocked SSH.